# Trouble making one div height move/equal with the other

Tags: html, css, height, width

I am having trouble making one div height move with the other/be equal. I need these to be equal as the left sidebar will have more content but I would still like the right div height to move with it as its a sidebar.

```
<div id="maincontainer">
     <div class="contentcontainer">

    <div class="postcontentcon">Nam eu auctor enim, id tincidunt dolor. Sed et lacinia sem. Donec pretium quam eget nunc vestibulum, vel sagittis nibh bibendum. Fusce eleifend sagittis ultrices. Nullam lobortis ultricies justo, nec tempus metus sollicitudin at. Proin sit amet turpis a orci ullamcorper pulvinar id vitae erat. Fusce sodales iaculis nulla ac faucibus. Vivamus blandit placerat nunc, nec dictum velit tincidunt in. Pellentesque elementum odio metus, eget fringilla nisi imperdiet quis. Etiam facilisis magna pellentesque lorem luctus condimentum. Nulla blandit ac ligula nec aliquam. Cras massa felis, condimentum condimentum ligula in, pharetra fermentum felis. Proin sed lorem interdum, lobortis lectus non, porta tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

    <div class="postsidebarcon">Hello</div>



 </div>
```

CSS

```
 body { background-color:#606061; }

 .contentcontainer {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width: 1017px;
height:auto;
 }

 .postcontentcon {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width: 694px;
background-color:#525253;
float:left;
  }

 .postsidebarcon {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width: 323px;
height:inherit;
background-color:#484848;
float:left;
 }
```

Comment: a few hints: faux-column, display:table/table-cell, display:flex;  clear ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few ways to do his :

1. `display:flex` and sizing your containers, default will draw child
   side by side **[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gsGkF)**
2. `display:table` on parent + `width` and `display:table-cell;` on child + `width` :  **[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Htlkj)**
3. clearing floats . `float` first element, set margin to second, add a pseudo with `clear:both` (or `left`/`right`) **[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/buoEh)**
4. faux-column technique, oldish but solid , fine here since parent container has a fixed `width` The idea is to draw the column onto `background` of parent : **[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBCAt)** (here i used a gradient for the demo, but usally it is an image. You can use multiple background nowdays.
5. there is other tricky ways with: floatting & hudge heights , negative margin ,overflow. some will even use absolute positionning  but you should stay away from using these.

Comment: i just tried the code, everythings good except for on safari! it doesnt get the layout, any sugggestions?

Comment: @user3648353 wich example have you tried on safari ?